# Crash when casting jobject to jstring - Android Studio, Android API 28, Pixel 4XL emulator, only when debugging

Tags: android, android-emulator, java-native-interface

I have a code that queries for a static field "READ_PHONE_STATE" from "android/Manifest$permission" via JNI interface:

```
env->GetStaticObjectField
```

This results in jobject. In all the examples I saw jobject was castable to jstring. They are both just c pointers (even tho value is "fake") so c-style cast shouldn't be a problem. However, I keep on getting crash. Information:

- I can cast jobject to any other derived class or even void* or int*. It crashes only when casting to jstring
- it crashes on jstring regardless of the order I put the casts in, even if I return jobject and do the cast in caller function.
- This happens only when I run Android API 28 emulator. Doesnt happen on Android API 27 emulator or Android API 16. I currently have no means to check on Android API 29+ or real hardware.
- Call GetStaticObjectField DOES return a value of 0xe1.
- Crash happens only when debugging

Here is the stack:

```
art_sigsegv_fault 0x00000000f1fcb1d0
art::FaultManager::HandleFault(int, siginfo*, void*) 0x00000000f1fcb774
art::art_fault_handler(int, siginfo*, void*) (.llvm.650222801) 0x00000000f1fcb49b
___lldb_unnamed_symbol22$$app_process32 0x0000000058a1a6af
___lldb_unnamed_symbol2$$libc.so 0x00000000f34a6c50
art::Thread::DecodeJObject(_jobject*) const 0x00000000f234c9b5
<unknown> 0x00000000f5a3f05d
dlsym 0x0000000058a19530
```

Here are the casts that I have done.

```
jobject fieldObject =  iface().env->GetStaticObjectField(iface().manifestpermissionClass,
                    iface().READ_PHONE_STATEFieldID);
log("fieldObject: %p", fieldObject);

void* castedToVoidPtr =  (void*) fieldObject;
log("castedToVoidPtr : %p", castedToVoidPtr);

{
    jobject a = (jobject) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}

{
    jarray a = (jarray) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}

{
    jobjectArray a = (jobjectArray) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}


{
    jbooleanArray a = (jbooleanArray) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}


{
    jbyteArray a = (jbyteArray) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}


{
    jcharArray a = (jcharArray) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}


{
    jshortArray a = (jshortArray) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}

{
    jstring a = (jstring) fieldObject;  // Crashes only when casting to jstring regardless of the order of casts and even if I move the cast to different function
    log("a: %p", a);
}

{
    jintArray a = (jintArray) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}

{
    jlongArray a = (jlongArray) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}

{
    jfloatArray a = (jfloatArray) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}

{
    jdoubleArray a = (jdoubleArray) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}

{
    jthrowable a = (jthrowable) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}

{
    jweak a = (jweak) fieldObject;
    log("a: %p", a);
}
```

Does anyone have an idea what is the issue and where is the bug?

Comment: Is the object in question actually a `jstring`?  Where is your other JNI code?  Are you checking the results of ***ALL*** of your JNI calls for errors ***and*** pending exceptions?

Comment: Object in question is what I get from the call to GetStaticObjectField with arguments received this way:
manifestpermissionClass = env->FindClass("android/Manifest$permission");
and
env->GetStaticFieldID(manifestpermissionClass, "READ_PHONE_STATE", "Ljava/lang/String;");
results of both are checked if they are NULL and they are not. On different emulators (Android API 27 and 16) I get a valid string that after translation to std::string gives value "Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" (or similar, I dont remember exactly)

Comment: The field READ_PHONE_STATEof Manifest$permission is indeed a string. I dont know if that matters a lot since all I'm doing is casting a c pointer value. Also I have successfully casted this jobject into all of these other types. It fails only with jstring.

Comment: I am not checking for pending exceptions. I'm relatively new to JNI and I was never aware that I should.